# Is updating AWS Windows Server 2012 AMI to 2012 R2 supported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

As Amazon does not yet provide a Windows Server 2012 R2 AMI (don't know if there's an ETA) do they support updating from 2012 to 2012 R2 using official Microsoft installation media?

Is it better to wait for an office AMI from AWS?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the upgrade to 2012 R2 Datacenter and it successfully activated against Amazon's KMS server.   At first I tried Standard since the 2012 AMI was Standard, but it would not activate.

It may not yet be officially supported, but it seems to work fine.

I did it by mounting the ISO I downloaded from Microsoft VLC.

Comment: This works on Microsoft Azure, as well (upgrading in-place) and will activate against the Microsoft KMS.  I doubt if either provider would officially support the method.